# FireMonkey iOS TButton OnKeyUp event fails

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I noticed that the `OnKeyUp` event processing does happen for a `TButton` control when running my iOS application on my iPhone and my iPad (but I believe it does on the Windows emulator).  The `OnKeyDown` event however seems to operate correctly.  This looks like a bug to me, but I am not sure.

I have installed service pack 1 on my Delphi XE2 install and recompiled - same result.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean it does **not** happen. I experience the same thing, so I cannot say it's a bug or a 'feature' but I at least I can offer confirmation.
I changed my code to react on OnKeyDown instead of OnKeyUp, which is a pain because for edit fields for example the text property is only filled after your code is fired - basically you are always one character 'late'.

Comment: Yes, sorry (typo), "does not happen".  Yes, very annoying, as you say as the text property is yet to be updated.  Can't determine when the user has typed the required number of characters in the field and process the input....